# why doesn't 0 0 * * 1 root hostname >> /tmp/hostname.txt work as a crontab?

Tags: cron

```
0 0 * * 1 root hostname >> /tmp/hostname.txt
```

The above cron entry should run midnight on monday and create a file in `/tmp` called `hostname.txt` with the output of the `hostname` command. But it is just a blank file that is created.  Why?

Comment: @drewbenn, I know, you're right.  Good point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When dealing with crontab entries it's important to make the distinction between a system level cron, typically in one of these locations:

- /etc/crontab
- /etc/cron.d/*
- /etc/cron.daily/*
- /etc/cron.weekly/*
- etc.

Or the user level variety, that are actually stored in this directory, `/var/spool/cron`:

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/spool/cron/
total 0
-rw------- 1 saml root 0 Jun  6 06:43 saml
```

You access these with the command `crontab -e` as a specific user. Even root can have these.

#### Your problem

The example you've included is the type of line you'd specify when making a system level type of `cron`. The only difference is the inclusion of the user with which the command should be run. This isn't necessary when creating a `crontab -e` type of entry since it's redundant, given the crontab entry is already designated to the user that created it.

So simply changing your line to this:

```
0 0 * * 1 hostname >> /tmp/hostname.txt
```

Fixes your issue.

#### How do the daily, weekly crons work?

You'll typically see an entry in your main `/etc/crontab` file like so:

```
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
22 4 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
42 4 1 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

These govern when the scripts in the respective directories will get run. So the daily's are every morning at 4:20AM my local time.

So if you want to run the command `hostname >> /tmp/hostname.txt` daily, you'd put it in a script, make it executable, and put the script file in the `cron.daily` directory.

*/etc/cron.daily/catchhostname.bash*

```
#!/bin/bash

hostname >> /tmp/hostname.txt
```

*cron.daily*

```
# ls -l |grep catch
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  118 Feb 28  2013 catchhostname.bash
```

Comment: What about if the same cron was put into /etc/cron.weekly?  Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: @GreggLeventhal - the one with the root in it should work from there.

Comment: If I use cron.weekly, will it run at the time I specified, or is there some time preconfigured for jobs in the weekly folder to run?

Comment: The time is preconfigured in /etc/crontab.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal - see updates.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that what you have above is the actual line in root's crontab:

```
0 0 * * 1 root hostname >> /tmp/hostname.txt
```

This line will run a command called "root", and pass it the parameter "hostname". If there is no command name "root" in /bin or /usr/bin (the default path for cron), you will get an empty file output.